# Find index of array by some string Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I'm working with an array like this one :

```
var table = ['view-only-access', 'restricted-access', 'full-access'];
```

I wanted to find the index by only string like `'view' , 'restricted', or 'full'.`
I have tried the .indexOf() but it requires the full string. does anyone know how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work
`table.findIndex(element=>element.includes('restricted'))`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var table = ['view-only-access', 'restricted-access', 'full-access'];

console.log(table.findIndex(i=>i.includes('view')));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const
  table    = ['view-only-access', 'restricted-access', 'full-access']
, f_search = str => table.findIndex( x => x.startsWith( str ) )
  ;
  
console.log( f_search('full') )         // 2
console.log( f_search('restricted') )  // 1
console.log( f_search('view') )       // 0
```

Comment: `startsWith` might be a little better than `includes`.

Comment: @Andy, you are right, it's better ; thanks :)